# DFM not found after reorganisation

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, dfm

I have a Delphi 7 project with this structure:

```
.dpr
foo.pas
*.pas
*.dfm
Bin/
debug/
```

Most of the source code, except for one file, is shared between other projects (although this is not relevant), so I did some reorganisation that looks like this:

```
.dpr
UniqueFile/
    foo.pas
Common/.pas
    *.pas
    *.dfm
Bin/
debug/
```

I changed the paths in the .dpr with the new structure, but when I try to compile for some reason it cannot find one of the .dfm files in `Common` folder. The error shown is:

`[Error] File not found: 'SomeFile.DFM'`

However, both the `.pas` and the corresponding `.dfm` are in that folder.

Did I miss some configuration?

---

EDIT: This file is included in the `.dpr` file like so:

```
uses
   ...
   SomeFile in 'Common/SomeFile.pas',
   ...
```

EDIT2: I've copied only the SomeFile.dfm file to the root folder, and it's compiling. For some reason it's still looking for that file in the old path?

EDIT3: I've included what @ken-white has pointed out but no luck. So now the .dpr looks like so:

```
uses
   ...
   SomeFile in 'Common/SomeFile.pas' {ChildFrame},
   ...
```

I've also double-checked this line in `SomeFile.pas`:

```
{$R *.DFM}
```

Another thing that I should point out is that the Build option works fine, but not the compiling.

Comment: When compiling a project A, the dfm is not copied to the dcu folder, and might appear missing to another project B that tries to use that dcu. I've had a similar issue with a form inside a package. The package's compiled units were written to a library path that was used by my application, but changes to the DFM didn't get in the application. I ended up writing a post-build script to copy the DFM's to the output path, but you can also solve this by making sure that both projects explicitly use the (pas) source file rather than the dcu.

Comment: @GolezTrol The thing is that I'm just compiling project A. For now, the only thing that I'm trying is compile the project with that new structure.

Comment: So, is SomeFile.pas explicitly included in project A? Or is it expected to find it in Common? If so, how is that path set? Library? Browsing path? Do you still have a SomeFile.dcu floating around that the project might be using instead of the pas file?

Comment: @GolezTrol The file is included in the .dpr file with a uses clause, I've updated the question. About the rest of the questions, It's the first time I use Delphi, so I'm not sure them.

Comment: Hmm. Tough cookie... Please check SomeFile.pas. There should be a line saying `{$R *.dfm}`. If that is not there, or if it looks differently, that could be the issue. The `*` refers to the current unit name. If there is a specific filename there, or a relative path, that could be a problem.

Comment: @GolezTrol I've updated the question again, that line looks fine, I tried different things but nothing.

Comment: Why are you using a forward slash `/`? Shouldn't it be a backslash \ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me that your issue (at least as of now) is that you are using a forward slash instead of a backslash.

```
uses
   ...
   SomeFile in 'Common/SomeFile.pas' {ChildFrame},
   ...
```

...should instead be...

```
uses
   ...
   SomeFile in 'Common\SomeFile.pas' {ChildFrame},
   ...
```

Comment: Nice catch, but it doesn't appear that the IDE cares. (The forward slash is an acceptable path separator on Windows.)

Comment: @Ken: most of the time, it is, indeed. But I have had situations where it didn't work.

Comment: @Rudy Which I guess would explain why OP reports `Compile` doesn't work but `Build` does.

Comment: @Jerry: I was talking about forward vs. backward slash and that the forward slash is not always accepted, on Windows. I doubt that this makes a difference between compile and build.

Comment: @Jerry: The slash direction makes zero difference between compile and build (if the IDE/compiler accept it in one, it would work in the other as well). It doesn't make any difference on either in D2007 or Berlin in a test on my machine with the information I've provided in my answer. The IDE doesn't seem to care one way or the other.

Comment: You're right Jerry, actually the IDE changes the forward slashes for backslashes. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the entry for the form in your .dpr file that tells the IDE there's a .dfm associated.

When you create a new VCL Forms application, the IDE writes the following entry to the project file:

```
uses
  Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1};
```

The information is the `{Form1}` tells the IDE to look for a .DFM file that contains the form information. You've said that the .pas file is in your new `Common` folder, but not told it that it should also look for a .dfm there as well. The IDE looks for it in the project folder instead, and can't find it there. Until, of course, you copy it into the project folder instead. :-)

Change your .dpr to read

```
uses
   ...
   SomeFile in 'Common/SomeFile.pas' {FormClass},
```

replacing `{FormClass}` with the name of the form variable from your `SomeFile` unit instead.

Comment: I had hope that this would fix it, but no luck :( It's a good point though, I'll investigate more this.

Comment: @cuoka: I can reproduce the issue you're having by moving a form and pas to a subfolder and then removing the `{Form1}` from the .dpr. I can also reproduce the fix by moving  the .dfm back into the project folder.

Comment: Were you able to fix it by adding the {FormClass} in the .dpr when the file is in the subfolder? Or that doesn't work for you either?

Comment: @cuoka: The solution in my answer works for me. As I said, I can reproduce the issue you're having, and fix it using the information I wrote in the answer.